# My Qt C++ program terminates in an unusual way

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I have a gui application that contains 2 main buttons, the first helps the user to choose 10 images and save them in a Mat array. The second button is for background subtraction and drawing the bounding rectangle. the program is working fine when I run it for the first time. but when i click again on the first button and choose other images and try to process them with the second button, sometimes it works fine but sometimes my program terminates in an unusual way without any error message in the console ( only this one : exited with code 255. ).
Here's my code :

```
void Principale::chooseImages_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog* _f_dlg = new QFileDialog(this);
  _f_dlg->setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
  _f_dlg->setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog, true);

  QListView *l = _f_dlg->findChild<QListView*>("listView");
  if (l) {
    l->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
   }
  QTreeView *t = _f_dlg->findChild<QTreeView*>();
   if (t) {
     t->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
    }

  _f_dlg->exec();
  _fnames = _f_dlg->selectedFiles();
  if(_fnames.size()!=10)
      QMessageBox::information(this, "Error!","choose 10 images!");

  else
  {
      image_choosed=true;
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
          Tab_IMG[i]=imread(_fnames.at(i).toStdString(),CV_16UC1);

      Entree entree;
      entree.setModal(true);
      entree.exec();
  }

void Principale::on_processing_clicked()
{
    if(!image_choosed)
        QMessageBox::information(this, "error!","choose 10 images!");
    else
    {
        chut=0;
        Mat BG; double moyenne=0;
        char chaine[20]="";int j=1;
        //Mat Subs;
        Vec3b couleur_dst,couleur_FG,couleur_sortie;
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
        {
            BG=imread(_fnames.first().toStdString(),CV_16UC1);


// background substraction

                Mat Subs(480, 640, CV_16UC1);
                absdiff(Tab_IMG[i],BG,Subs);
                BG.convertTo(BG,CV_8UC1,1.0/255.0);
                Tab_IMG[i].convertTo(Tab_IMG[i],CV_8UC1,1.0/255.0);
                Subs.convertTo(Subs,CV_8UC1);
                threshold(Subs,Subs,25, 255,THRESH_BINARY);
                Mat ones(3,3,CV_8UC1);
                morphologyEx(Subs,Subs,MORPH_OPEN,ones,Point(1,-1),1); // try 2 instead of 1
                erode(Subs,Subs,ones,Point(1,-1),1);

//--------------------- bounding rectangle 


            Rect bounding_rect;
            int largest_area=0;
            int largest_contour_index=0;
            Mat dst(Subs.rows,Subs.cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar::all(0));
            Mat thr=Subs;
            vector<vector<Point> > contours;
            vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
            findContours( thr, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
            for( int k = 0; k< contours.size(); k++ )
            {
                double a=contourArea( contours[k],false);
                if(a>largest_area)
                {
                   largest_area=a;
                   largest_contour_index=k;
                   bounding_rect=boundingRect(contours[k]);
                }
            }

            Scalar color( 255,255,255);
            drawContours( dst, contours,largest_contour_index, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );
            rectangle(dst, bounding_rect,Scalar(255,0,0),2, 8,0);
            int compteur=0; double moyenne=0;  int seuille=255; double depth;
            Mat sortie(Tab_IMG[i].rows,Tab_IMG[i].cols,CV_8UC1);
            sortie.setTo(0);
            Vec3b couleur_dst,couleur_FG,couleur_sortie;
            for(int x=0;x<dst.cols;x++)
            {
                for(int y=0;y<dst.rows;y++)
                {
                    couleur_dst= dst.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));
                    couleur_FG=Tab_IMG[i].at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));
                    if((couleur_dst.val[0]==255)&&(couleur_dst.val[1]==255)&&(couleur_dst.val[2]==255))
                    {
                        sortie.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = couleur_FG;
                        seuille=couleur_FG.val[0];
                        depth=(3640*couleur_FG.val[0])/255;
                        moyenne+=depth;
                        compteur++;
                    }
                 }
             }
             moyenne=moyenne/compteur;
             Tab_dist[i]=moyenne;
             Tab_silh[i]=sortie;
             Tab_rect[i]=bounding_rect;
             Tab_surf[i]=bounding_rect.width*bounding_rect.height;
             if(i==1)
                  surf_one=Tab_surf[i];
             else
                  moy_dif_surf+=Tab_surf[i]-surf_one;
            Tab_rect[i]=bounding_rect;

         Tab_silh[0]=imread("C:\\Users\\Eden\\Desktop\\Images\\noire.png",CV_16UC1);
        /*Sortie sortie;
        sortie.setModal(true);
        sortie.exec();*/
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The problem is not in background subtraction because i tried to remove the code below it and the program works fine no matter how many times i click on the two buttons, i think the problem is in bounding rectangle code. please help me detect it :)

Comment: Are you sure compteur in moyenne=moyenne/compteur is > 0?

Comment: you should really be using a debugger. Qt-Creator has one built in. You can open your pro file in creator and use the start debug button to gain some insight into why your program terminates

Comment: yes because i initialize it (int compteur=0;) then increment it inside the (if condition)

Comment: how can i do it? ( debuggin thing )

Comment: I have seen the if condition... but who says that it really is executed? Just by looking at the code without knowing the input data, it is hard to tell.

Comment: Here's the input image http://www7.0zz0.com/2015/03/29/16/745018388.jpg  the second image is the same image but the person is colored in white . that's why i'm sure that the condition is executed. anyway,  the problem is in that same loop ( i eliminated the code below it ) here's the error code now : http://www4.0zz0.com/2015/03/29/16/316871318.png

Comment: @EadhunDi to use the debugger just open up Qt Creator and click on the "Run debug" button right below the "Run" button.

Comment: "without any error message in the console" Yep, the OpenCV error 'insufficient memory' and the thrown exception is probably just entertainment and totally unrelated to your problem. ;-)

Comment: With "run debug" button i get this error now:

http://www10.0zz0.com/2015/03/29/16/587888168.png

Comment: after eliminating codes, it seems that the problem is in this instruction (inside if condition )

 sortie.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = couleur_FG;
but i can't understand why

Comment: Well i've found the problem, it's because the input/output images are in CV_UC1 format and i'm accessing their pixels as Vec3b ones. anyway, i don't know how to get and set CV_UC1 images's pixel :/

Comment: "We are no longer accepting answers from this account" ... Sorry but i can't post the answer, can anybody do it for me? here's the answer to the problem : The problem is in this instruction "sortie.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = couleur_FG;", exactly when i try to access the pixels as Vec3b ones which is incorrect because the image is defined as one-channel image. The solution is to use "uchar" instead of "Vec3b" .

Answer (score 0):

([Answer moved from comments to a community wiki.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

The OP wrote:

> The problem is in this instruction `sortie.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = couleur_FG;`, exactly when I try to access the pixels as `Vec3b` ones which is incorrect because the image is defined as one-channel image. The solution is to use `uchar` instead of `Vec3b` .